# PHP не может принять POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Всем привет, есть проблема, мне нужно передать из поля input текст, а php файл как-будто не видит её, попробовал var_dump($_POST), но там пустой массив. Делаю через ajax.
HTML:

```
'''
<form action="index.php" method='get' id="form">
    
        <input type="text" class="h" name="comment" id="comment">
        <input type="button" id="y" class="bron">
    </form>
'''
```

PHP:

```
'''
    session_start();
    include 'index.html';
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=resto; charset=UTF8", 'root', 'root');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    $connect->query("UPDATE `resto`.`stol` SET `stol1`= 1 WHERE 1");
    if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
        $r = $_POST['comment'];
        echo $r;
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
'''
```

JS:

```
'''
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // $('.h').hide();
            $('.kv').mouseover(function(){
                $(this).css('border','0.3vw solid red');
                $(this).html('Столик занят');
            })
            $('.kv').mouseout(function(){
                $(this).css('border','0.3vw solid #d4cc70');
                $(this).html('');
                $(this).css('top','-3vw');
            })
            $('.bron').on('click', function(){
                var comment = $('comment').val();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "index.php",
                    data: { 
                        comment: comment,
                    }
                })
            })

        });
'''
```

Comment: Ты передаёшь данные методом **GET**...... вопрос: откуда взяться данным в переменной POST?

Comment: Исправил, ничего не изменилось

Comment: отладка и выявление ошибок в руки берём и смотрим.... как в js так и в php (ссылки выше). Можешь начать с пыхи если угодно

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте селектор, с `var comment = $('comment').val();` на `var comment = $('#comment').val();`, а то у вас получается, что вы ищете тег с `<comment>`

**PS**: И в php еще вы обращаетесь к `$_POST['comment']`, хотя у вас нужно обращаться к `$_POST['data']['comment']` (Тут я не прав)

**PSS**: в html уберите метод, как вам сказали в комментариях

Comment: Нет, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @AlDv, добавил еще ошибку в ответ

Comment: Никаких `$_POST['data']`, просто `$_POST['comment']`

Comment: @u_mulder, да, точно, ступил